# What is a good way to handle multiple repeated entries?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to make a lookup table for some matching code I plan to use, but I am having trouble making the table itself. My tab separated data looks like this:

```
1002_f_at       P33261 /// Q16743
1003_s_at       P32302 /// A8K647 /// Q2YD84 /// A0N0R2
1004_at P32302 /// A8K647 /// Q2YD84 /// A0N0R2
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
1002_f_at P33261
1002_f_at Q16743
1003_s_at P32302
1003_s_at A8K647 
1003_s_at Q2YD84 
1003_s_at A0N0R2
1004_at   P32302
```

Which is also tab separated. I was hoping for an awk or Perl solution but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works beyond this

```
    sed 's: /// :\n\t:g'
```

which gives me:

```
    1002_f_at P33261
              Q16743
    1003_s_at P32302
              A8K647 
              Q2YD84 
              A0N0R2
    1004_at   P32302
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]*///[[:blank:]]+*' '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $i}' file
1002_f_at P33261
1002_f_at Q16743
1003_s_at P32302
1003_s_at A8K647
1003_s_at Q2YD84
1003_s_at A0N0R2
1004_at P32302
1004_at A8K647
1004_at Q2YD84
1004_at A0N0R2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is trivial in Perl

```
perl -nE'($s,@r) = /\w+/g; say "$s\t$_" for @r' myfile
```

#### output

```
1002_f_at   P33261
1002_f_at   Q16743
1003_s_at   P32302
1003_s_at   A8K647
1003_s_at   Q2YD84
1003_s_at   A0N0R2
1004_at P32302
1004_at A8K647
1004_at Q2YD84
1004_at A0N0R2
```

Answer (score 1):

Perlishly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    my ( $key, $values ) = m/^\s*(\w+)\s*(.*)/;
    foreach my $value ( split( " /// ", $values ) ) {
        print "$key $value\n";
    }
}
```

With your data prints:

```
1002_f_at P33261
1002_f_at Q16743
1003_s_at P32302
1003_s_at A8K647
1003_s_at Q2YD84
1003_s_at A0N0R2
1004_at P32302
1004_at A8K647
1004_at Q2YD84
1004_at A0N0R2
```

This could be reduced to a one liner thus:

```
 perl -ne '( $k, $v ) = m/^\s*(\w+)\s*(.*)/; for ( split( " /// ", $v ) ) { print "$k $_\n" }' yourfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/\s+/\t/;s#^((\S+)\t\S+)\s*///#\1\n\2#;P;D' file
```

Replace multiple spaces by a tab and then replace the first occurence of `///` by the first two fields a newline and the first field. Print upto the first newline and then remove that line and repeat.